# Trouble installing Zurb Foundation 6.3.1 in Debian 8

Tags: npm, debian, zurb-foundation, command-line-interface, zurb-foundation-6

I am installing Zurb Foundation 6.3.1 in Debian 8 but after running npm install --global foundation-cli I get this error when I start to run the foundation new command.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/lib/commands/info.js:7
module.exports = function(args = {}) {
                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208382/cant-create-a-new-project-with-foundation-css